# Create two columns table from td in one row

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create two columns table from the next td list via jQuery:

```
<table>
  <tr id="dw">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      ...
      <td>n</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I expecting something like that:

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 ...
 <tr>
    <td>n-1</td>
    <td>n</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Could anyone complete my code?

```
$('#dw tr').each(function(){
    $('<tr>').insertAfter(this).append($('td:eq(1)',this))
})
```

Comment: what you want to do here?.  you want to modify the existing table or create another table

Comment: your jquery code will always returns one element because `#` is unique id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to create new `tr`, to insert current `td`s with index more than 1 to newly created `tr` and to append this new `tr` after existed one in table.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/he9pmszk/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var newTr = $('<tr>');
    $('#dw td:gt(1)').appendTo(newTr);
    newTr.insertAfter('#dw');
});
```

**Update** for updated question.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/he9pmszk/1/)

```
<table id="table">
  <tr id="dw">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var currentTr = $('<tr>');
    var table = $('#table');
    $('#dw td').each(function(index)
    {
        currentTr.append(this);
        if (index % 2)
        {
            table.append(currentTr);
            currentTr = $('<tr>');
        }
    });
    $('#dw').remove();
});
```

Comment: One problem I found is that if you have an odd number of `<td>`s, the last one will be lost. Not sure about the OP's specs on that.

Comment: It can be covered using next solution: if (index % 2) {
                table.append(currentTr);
                currentTr = $('<tr>');
            } else {
                table.append(currentTr);
            }

Comment: @AkiraYamaokaNC you can simplify your code: `table.append(currentTr); if (index % 2) {  currentTr = $('<tr>'); }`

Answer (score 1):

I see one problem - You are using the selector $('#dw tr') - meaning that you are looking for an element with the ID #dw INSIDE a tr. In your example, the #dw is the actual tr. So this selector wouldn't work

why not just use $('#dw')?

Comment: `$('#dw tr')` looks for `<tr>` elements inside elements with `#dw`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table").append('<tr></tr>'); // generate the second row container
$("td:gt(1)").appendTo('tr+tr'); // move the 3rd-4th td to the new row
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this solution is hardcoded and can be applied for different <td> element numbers.

Comment: Just adjust the selectors accordingly.  I just made it as simple as possible for the example.  It would be good to actually place an empty tr in the html if you can so you can avoid generating it with jQuery.. would be more efficient.  And add a class to the td's you want to move to simply selecting them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple rows, do like this,

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).index() > 1
    }).wrapAll("<tr></tr>")

    $(this).after($(this).find("tr"));
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/425/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I'm trying to split: <table>
  <tr id="dw">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table> to the table with tr with two td inside